# how to include js file in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, jakarta-ee

I'm a beginner into jee.  I want to include a js file into my jsp file.

jsp file:
`<script  type="text/javascript" src="js/controle_button.js">
</script>`

js file:

```js
function ajout()
{
 alert("ok");
 i++;
 var temp = "environement" +i;
 var div = document.createElement('div');
 div.innerHTML = '<label>'+temp+'<span class="requis"></span></label> <input type="text" name="environement+'+i+'" ><input type="button" id="add_kid()" onClick="ajout()" value="+" /><input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeKid(this)">';
 
 document.getElementById('env').appendChild(div);
 }
function removeKid(div) { 
    document.getElementById('env').removeChild( div.parentNode );
 i--;
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem? What errors are you getting or what indication of something not functioning as intended?

Comment: You will just include the script as part of the `jsp` as part of the footer or header, based on the other dependencies, i.e what is `controle_button.js` is dependent on

Comment: @Omar Berrami what you have here looks ok. In order for us to be able to help, you need to include the error message  - or to describe in detail what is not working. Did you called that functions and didn't work? I can't say more at this point..

Comment: the problem is that i called the function ajout() and she didn't work and i dont have any error message i think the problem he canont find the script
i have created a folder js in the the project folder  where i create file controle_button.js @Alon

Answer (score 0):

hello thank you for your help the solution for my probleme it's just to move JS folder to WebContent folder  thank you again .